# What's the logic behind the "Pimp my Rabbid" minigame?

Tags: raving-rabbids-tv-party

Most of the games in Raving Rabbids: Tv Party are straightforward, with the exception of the "Pimp my Rabbid" minigame: we're asked to dress a Rabbid according to a vague description, choosing between dozens of possible outfits.

The problem is I'm having wildly swinging degrees of success, since I cannot seem to find a pattern between the adjectives in the description and the outfits among which I can choose. Is there any definitive correlation (1:1 or close to that) or do I have to keep using my common sense?